# How to add a new Tab on Android Application Page (Apps,Widget, (my tab))?

Tags: android

Please see the picture below. How to add a third Tab on this page? I want to add my application a search tab on the other side next to widget tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible simply because this Launcher is actually an application that you can't access to unless you have the code or both apps should share the same UserID in the manefist like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.something"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:sharedUserId="com.example"> //here
```

and even if you managed to add 3rd tab, it will be only applicable on this manufacturer launcher only like on Samsung launcher because HTC has different launcher than Samsung and the rest.

Best luck on finding a way

Comment: Oh so it seems like you need to be a developer from Android phone company in order to do these things?

Comment: well you can see in the market that there are many launcher applications that are developed by individuals like Go launcher or Nova launcher... if you are interested to develop a launcher here is a [tutorial](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/)